# [cps], [continuation-passing] -> [continuation-passing-style]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

The [continuation-passing](/questions/tagged/continuation-passing) and [cps](/questions/tagged/cps) tags both refer to [Continuation-passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style), and should therefore be merged. I also think it's better to use the full term, so we should make a new tag [continuation-passing-style](/questions/tagged/continuation-passing-style) and make the others synonyms of that. Does that sound good?

I've already retagged the three questions tagged [cps](/questions/tagged/cps) that were not about continuation-passing style.

Another option is to merge them into the [continuations](/questions/tagged/continuations) tag, but that's a broader topic.

**Update:** This doesn't seem to have attracted much interest, despite the bounty. But since I haven't heard any protests either, and there aren't *that* many questions involved, I'm tempted to just go ahead and make the changes myself. I'll give it another 24 hours unless I hear anything else.

Comment: I was also tempted to do that (manually). What will you choose then? [tag:continuation-passing] & [tag:cps] renamed into [tag:continuation-passing-style] or [tag:continuations] ?

Comment: @j0k: I prefer [continuation-passing-style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continuation-passing-style). It's good enough to stand on its own, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I've gone through the questions manually and changed them to [continuation-passing](/questions/tagged/continuation-passing). (Unfortunately, `continuation-passing-style` was 1 character too long). I also removed the tag from some questions that didn't need it and added it to some others where it was appropriate.

However, there still needs to be a synonym from the old [cps](/questions/tagged/cps) to [continuation-passing](/questions/tagged/continuation-passing), which I am currently unable to suggest. (Could've sworn I had answered a few questions about it...). If a mod could be so kind as to add it for me, that would be great.